# When is the feature of partitioning on integer column available in BIGQUERY table?

Tags: google-bigquery

Do we know when google will enable partitioning on integer column in BIGQUERY table? And can we partition BIGQUERY table after it is created or it has to be partitioned at the same time when the BIGQUERY table is created?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So called [Integer range partitioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#integer_range) are available already as Beta in a pre-release state

Table must be set as partitioned during its creation as in example below

```
CREATE TABLE `project.dataset.table`
PARTITION BY RANGE_BUCKET(customer_id, GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 100, 10)) AS 
SELECT 1 AS customer_id, DATE '2019-10-01' AS day
```

See more details in [Creating and using integer range partitioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-integer-range-partitions)

Comment: sure. consider also voting up the answer if it helped - it is equally important on SO :o)